# What's this new Chinese character which looks like 座?

Tags: characters

I keep seeing this new Chinese character on social media:

> [image]

What is this?

Comment: Someone wanted to edit 座 into the title, but I'm thinking we could put the IDS there instead. Would this be right: ⿸广⿻土人人? Or just describe it: 交错入座的「座」字?

Comment: ⿻土人人 is not right, maybe ⿻⿻人土人 is OK. The whole thing should be ⿸广⿻⿻人土人.

Comment: @Mo. I suggested 座 for the title. Please go ahead if you have a better suggestion.

Comment: I'd suggest ⿸广◰人⿷土人 where ◰ is a place-holder for a non-existing IDC (Ideographic Description Character) which I *thought* was added to Unicode at some point but now I can't find it in v13. FWIW personally I only ever use ⿻ as a last resort. I feel unhappy about the missing ◰ as it is also needed to describe characters like 头 and so on.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Technically it isn't a new Chinese character but a Japanese character.

[Eileen Chow](https://twitter.com/chowleen/status/1343190637630263297?s=20) posted about this on Twitter saying:

> Winner of 2020’s new kanji contest in Japan: the character 座 (seat), ingeniously redesigned as a neologism for “social distance.”
>
> Note the two 人 (person) radicals in the original 座 are now positioned farther away from one another!

You can find a whole list of competition candidates on the official [Sousaku Kanji](https://sousaku-kanji.com/) website.

---

On her twitter thread Eileen Chow also shows off some other characters with explanations. Here's another interesting one for the times:

> [image]
>
> I like this one because it is a bilingual visual pun - a 76yo entrant transformed the bottom half of the character 会 (meeting) into a “Z” to make...you guessed it, “web conferencing via Zoom”.

---

Seeing as they are all 漢字 - they could be easily adoptable into Chinese.

Comment: 30 years from now these would be "standard" characters taught in schools.

Comment: it is a coined character, ^_^, it suggests avoid sitting in same table. I don't think this glyph will be adopted, instead it is just for entertainment.

Comment: That all depends on how long we need to keep “social distancing” for, I guess.

Comment: I'm so curious what all these new characters describe! Unfortunately, I don't know Japanese.